# variable == [ ]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, pycharm

el codigo es :

```
if recs == []:
```

Esto me retorna un False.
Pero no entiendo lo de '[ ]', la lista esta no esta definida en ningún sitio, que tiene que pasar para que me retorne un True?

Comment: Que `recs` sea una lista vacía

Comment: pienso que un código más python es: `if not recs:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esa sentencia verifica si la variable `recs`(que de seguro es una lista) esta vacia.
Puedes hacer pruebas para ver su funcionamiento:

```
def verificarLista(recs):
    if recs == []:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")

lista=[]
lista1=[2,3]
lista2=["hola","mundo"]

verificarLista(lista)   # RESULTADO: TRUE
verificarLista(lista1)  # RESULTADO: FALSE
verificarLista(lista2)  # RESULTADO: FALSE
```